# What is the meaning of KDZ file name format?

Tags: lg, files

What is the meaning of LG's `.kdz` file name format?

For instance, a KDZ file: `D85530B_00_1217.kdz` (Marshmallow for LG G3 D855).

After the model no (D855), the terms like 30B, 30C etc. are coming. What does it mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: maybe it should be moved to android instead of closed

Answer (score 3):

KDZ is the format which LG uses when posting official firmware releases on their website. KDZ are all stock releases from LG. Custom ROMs do not come as KDZ, the tend to come as ZIP file.

KDZ files are flashed with LG Flash Tool or LGUP, and ZIP files are flashed with TWRP.

- 10 means KitKat
- 20 means Lollipop
- 30 means Marshmallow

A/B/C/etc is revision number.

1217 is the release date 17-Dec.

It can be confusing because there are many different versions of D855 for different carriers and regions, with different revision numbers.

For example in the UK, the latest O2 Lollipop version is 20n, but the latest unlocked Lollipop version seems to be up to 21c, but both are up to date with the latest Android security patches.

Comment: It might be better to say that the 2-digit number stands for "major revisions" instead of just locking them to a certain Android version (since we now have phones with version 40+ which also corresponds to Marshmallow). Other than that, +1.